# Quicksort c++ first element as pivot

Tags: c++, quicksort

I have something like this and I want to have first element as pivot.
Why this program is still does not working?

```
void algSzyb1(int tab[],int l,int p)
{
    int x,w,i,j;
    i=l;      //l is left and p is pivot, //i, j = counter 
    j=p;
    x=tab[l];   
    do
    {
        while(tab[i]<x) i++;
        while(tab[j]>x) j--;
        if(i<=j)
        {
            w=tab[i];
            tab[i]=tab[j];
            tab[j]=w;
            i++;
            j--;
        }           
    }
    while(!(i<j));
    if(l<j) algSzyb1(tab,l,j);
    if(i<p) algSzyb1(tab,i,p);
}
```

Comment: Use **meaningful names** of your variables and use **comments** before each complex expression to clarify its use. This will make your code easy to read and correct.

Comment: And use comments that make sense if you _don't_ know what the code is doing.

Comment: If you write a comment "l is left, p is pivot", why don't you just call the variables left and pivot?

Comment: `std::partition` (or indeed `std::sort`) save reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Clearly homework, and reinventing the wheel is the purpose of the homework.

Comment: you can also use `std::swap` to swap two elements. saves the use of a temporary

Comment: When I saw the title of this question, I thought the question was going to be "What are the pros and cons of choosing the first element as the pivot, as opposed to, say, the middle element?" That would have been a nice little question.

Comment: why would you use `while(!(i<j))` instead of `while(i>=j)`, unless you are making a [Goldberg machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, not really checking what it does, just looking at the individual lines, this one line stands out:

```
while(!(i<j));
```

I look at that line, and I think: There is a bug somewhere round here. I haven't actually looked at the code so I don't know what the bug is, but I look at this single line and it looks wrong.

Comment: You do realize this is not a free-standing 'while' statement, but that it controls the do-loop above it? (Still wrong though, but maybe for a different reason.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to decrement j before incrementing i.

```
    while (tab[j]>x ) j--;
    while (tab[i]<x && i < j) i++;
```

Also I have added an extra condition to ensure that i doesn't sweep past j. (Uninitialized memory read).

The pivot is slightly mis-named, as the end result is a sorted element, but this and the [wikipedia page : quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) both move the pivot into the higher partition, and don't guarantee the item in the correct place.

The end condition is when you have swept through the list

```
while( i < j );  /* not !(i<j) */
```

At the end of the search, you need to test a smaller set.   The code you had created a stack overflow, because it repeatedly tried the same test.

```
  if (l<j) algSzyb1(tab, l, j);
  if (j+1<p) algSzyb1(tab, j+1, p);
```

Full code

```
void algSzyb1(int tab[], int l, int p)
{
    int x, w, i, j;
    i = l;
    j = p;
    x = tab[l]; //wróć tu później :D
    do
    {
        while (tab[j]>x ) j--;
        while (tab[i]<x && i < j) i++;
        if (i < j)
        {
            w = tab[i];
            tab[i] = tab[j];
            tab[j] = w;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    } while ((i<j));
    if (l<j) algSzyb1(tab, l, j);
    if (j+1<p) algSzyb1(tab, j+1, p);
}
```